# Removing extra new lines with print() in python

Tags: python

I have written these lines in a file

```
AA
BB
CC
```

With the following python code

```
f = open("foo.txt",'r')
for line in f:
    print (line)
```

I see that there is a newline between each line that is reads from

```
AA

BB

CC

# terminal prompt
```

How can I remove those new lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because each line includes newline character(s), and print prints a newline character after everything else, for a total of up-to 2 newlines (the last line might have only 1).

You could strip the newline characters from the line.

```py
f = open("foo.txt",'r')
for line in f:
    print(line.rstrip('\r\n'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can instead call `print` as

```py
print(line, end='')
```

to prevent `print` from adding an newline on top of the ones read from the file.